# Will there be an issue if I take 10 kilograms of yerba mate on an airplane?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, airport-security

Mate is a traditional South American infusion, which is not common and usually expensive in Europe. I'm travelling to France soon so I'm taking a bunch of it (the yerba mates leaves, not a liquid) for friends, and friends of friends. I'm wondering if this will make my luggage look extremely suspicious, and perhaps cause me to experience a delay while they check it or something.

I have previously taken a couple kilograms without any issue, but this time it would be about half of my case :).

UPDATE: I ended up taking 6kg, along with 6 bottles of wine/liquors and absolutely nothing happened :).

Comment: 10 liters of liquid in your luggage will attract attention...

Comment: It's not liquid! It's a herb, much like tea.

Comment: It may depend on whether your country has some arrangement with France about phyto security. The quantity you mention might be considered for commercial use which might not be allowed without a certificate but I am not an expert in this area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The import of plants or plant parts into the European Union may be restricted or prohibited if listed as:

- Invasive
- Likely to carry pests or pathogens
- Endangered
- Narcotic

None of this applies to yerba mate, *Ilex paraguariensis*. Plants for which no restrictions apply do not have to be declared, unless the total value of imported goods exceeds duty and tax free allowances.

Comment: Looking at the images of [mate leaves](https://i.imgur.com/nvZkx5A.png) and looking at images of [coca plant leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca#/media/File:Erythroxylum_novogranatense_var._Novogranatense_(retouched).jpg), I can see the chance of someone confusing them.

Comment: @jhadenfeldt In my case it's more like this: https://http2.mlstatic.com/yerba-mate-cachamate-mezcla-de-hierbas-amarilla-x-1-kg-D_NQ_NP_925626-MLA26261263507_102017-F.jpg, already ground and all packaged up.

Answer (score 2):

You may be subject to an inspection an questioning, due to suspicions.

Provided to you:

- Act in a calm manner
- Explain why you are carrying out
- Abide with local custom laws and regulations
- Let them search your luggage

You should expect a possible bag search, even them analysing it. Also bear in mind of recent drug stories in France like [this one](https://amp.theguardian.com/world/2019/feb/18/air-cocaine-drug-trafficking-trial-begins-in-france), so a delay of an hour should not surprise you.